# Write large data set around 100 GB having just one partition to hive using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to write large dataset to a partitioned hive table (partitioned by date) using spark .The data set results in just one date, so just one partition. It is taking long time to write to table. It is also causing shuffling while writing . My code does not contain any join. It has just some map function, filter and union. How to efficiently write this kind of data to hive table? [Check image of spark UI here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgp9t.png)

Comment: Please share some example of your code ? Generally, try to 1. split union into multiple queries 2. apply filters as soon as possible in pipeline. 3. see if sequence of fields are same to avoid order mixed up.

Comment: From your screenshot. write itself (stage# 3) takes only 11 minutes. I'd rather focus on the data prep stage #2, and try to figure out why it takes 7+ hours.